# Smoke emitter not rendering in viewport

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm following [this tutorial](http://vimeo.com/24551362) and at 32:45 he tests out the smoke emitter, and I've followed every step to that point, and it doesn't work for me. He starts explaining how to do it at 30:15. [Here's a link to my .blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yse3n1d3tywc02f/RSKBS%20Intro%20v2.blend), can someone please explain to me (very simply) what I'm doing wrong here?

p.s. sorry for asking so many questions!

Comment: Please don't just post a blend file and ask someone to look at it for you. Write a detailed question outlining your specific problem.

Comment: Sorry! I'm new here and don't really know the rules and such. I'll give more details next time :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. You can always just run through the [quick tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the domain settings on what should be the emitter object.

The domain should be the cube around the cylinder, and the emitter object should be the cylinder inside it (see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Smoke)).

Note that the smoke simulator was updated a bit in blender 2.64, so to get an the same effect in 2.70a:

1. Enable the smoke domain for the cube object:

   [image]

   *Adaptive domain* is a setting which was added in 2.64, and it basically just skips calculating parts of the domain which don't have smoke in or near them. Enabling it should speed up the simulation without affecting the result.
2. Enable the smoke flow physics on the cylinder (in your file this was set to domain)

   [image]

   Make sure *Initial* velocity is enabled. You may also want to up the number subframe smaples, but note that this will slow down the simulation.